# SQLite delete item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i would like to know, how to delete item from a listview and SQLite database. I have this code. What should i change because items are not deleting from the listview. This is my whole code, i dont know what to change in it

**DBAdapter.java**

```
static final String ROW_ID ="id";
static final String NAME ="name";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DBNAME="m_DB";
static final String TBNAME="m_TB";
static final int DBVERSION='1';

static final String CREATE_TB="CREATE TABLE m_TB(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + "name TEXT NOT NULL);";

final Context c;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DBHelper helper;
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.c = ctx;
    helper = new DBHelper(c);
}


private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("DBAdapter","Upgrading DB");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m_TB");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public DBAdapter openDB()
{
    try {
        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    helper.close();
}

public long add(String name)
{
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME,name);
        return db.insert(TBNAME,ROW_ID,cv);
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public Cursor getAllNames()
{
    String[] columns={ROW_ID,NAME};
    return db.query(TBNAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView lv;
    EditText nameTxt;
    Button savebtn,retrievebtn;
    ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nameTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        savebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        retrievebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.retrieveBtn);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,books);
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.openDB();
                long result = db.add(nameTxt.getText().toString());

                if(result > 0)
                {
                    nameTxt.setText("");
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                db.close();
            }
        });

        retrievebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                books.clear();
                db.openDB();
                Cursor c = db.getAllNames();

                while (c.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name = getString(1);
                    books.add(name);
                }
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                db.close();
            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),books.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
        menu.add("Delete");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getTitle()== "Delete")
        {
            books.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I inserted this to DPAdapter

```
public void delete(String name)throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { name };
        db.delete(TBNAME, NAME+ "=?", whereArgs);
        db.close();
    }
```

and this to MainActivity

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
        menu.add("Delete");
    }

 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String name = info.toString();
        if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
            db.delete(name);
            books.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

but nothing is happening. How can i call that delete method??

Comment: What's the `books` variable? This is missing an important part of the code.

Comment: I edited and inserted all code above

Answer (score 1):

Compare Strings with .equals rather than "==" :

```
if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete"))
        {
            books.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

also you need to add the delete query to delete the items from SQlite as currently you are removing items from listview only.

Comment: what code should i write in order to delete it from SQLite?

Comment: Refer Here for how to write code : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DeleteDbRow

Comment: WHat should i write instead of COLUMN_NAME?

Comment: so is it fine ? db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);

Comment: maybe you can look at mine  public boolean onContextItemSelected code?

Comment: It should be db.delete(TBNAME, NAME+ "=?", whereArgs); Is it working ?

Comment: you need to tell me what do you want to do . Are you comparing the name  (info.toString()) string against the name column in your db?

Comment: in info.toString() i wanted to get a name of an item in a listView because delete method needs string input and books.remove(item) needs item's ID

Comment: I am actually trying to do something because i am new at java and i need to get this app working

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can remove item from your `SQLite Database`, you need to include it in `DBAdapter`.

```
public void delete(String name)throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (db == null) {
        return;
    }
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { name };
    db.delete("YOUR_TABLE_NAME", "COLUMN_NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);
    db.close();
}
```

and to remove it from your `ListView` you need to remove item from list and then notify your adapter like this

```
YourArraylist.remove([index]);
YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: So i just need to insert this to DBAdapter and change variables by myself and what should i write in MainActivity?

Comment: second part is for `MainActivity` where you want to delete the item

Comment: but method is called delete so i should write YourArraylist.delete([index]); ?

Comment: I updated post, can you look at it? I dont know what to do. I pasted your code to DBAdapter and nothing is working

Comment: what should i write inside  if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) { 
        } ??